# How can I purchase Olympic themed skins?

Tags: overwatch

There are those skins representing different countries for some characters, Tracer-Great Britain. How can I obtain them ?

Comment: Asked the question for the sake of having an open question to a now present questioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer : You "never could". These were awarded through Summer Games 2016 LootBoxes. The lootboxes were awarded through regular gameplay and by purchasing them ***at the time***. There was never a way to unlock them directly.

Long Answer from Jeff Kaplan :

Comment: This answer is false, you never could directly purchase skins with ingame currency.

Comment: I meant to say by purchasing lootboxes. Precising. Thanks for the insight

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer is correct, you were never able to purchase those Seasonal items with in-game currency. You could purchase the themed loot boxes, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I think the answer is still misleading with that "You can't anymore" when the title is "How can I purchase [them]?".

Comment: The skins should also be available in summer games 2017 boxes, potentially

Comment: There won't be Olympic Games in 2017...

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer How can you buy something that isn't available anymore then ?

Comment: @Katyr: Blizzard was very careful to avoid any references to "Olympics" in this event. The event was called "Summer Games", I don't see any reason why they couldn't bring the boxes back next summer. (Doesn't make a whole lot of financial sense for a company to develop a product that people can only buy for two weeks every four years).

Comment: I feel like the avoidance of mention of the Olympics was towards the backlash on the "coverage" of the Olympics (weren't allowed to talk about the event unless you paid a "coverage fee"). It makes sense when you introduce the concept of rarity in the mix.

Comment: Using "anymore" implies that you could purchase them before, which you could not.

Comment: @MageXy I think limited offers of boxes sell alot more then through the whole year. This is probably not the only event that will happen either.